# Long running Process using Task objects and a Monitor Thread

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am attempting to monitor a long running process. Right now the process created new Task objects for all the small pieces, but I need some way to monitor their progress to send status to a UI.

```
ExecutionContext ctx = new ExecutionContext()
        {
            Result = result,
            LastCount = result.Values.Count
        };

        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var dataSlice in dataObjects)
                {
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                   {
                       // Do Some Work
                   }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            });

        ctx.ParentTask = t;


        Task monitor = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
            {
                ctx.LastCount = ctx.Result.Values.Count;

            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

My problem, or perhaps question is, if I force my monitor task to wait (via a SpinWait or Sleep) will it possibly lock part of the Tasks created above it? I need the monitor to check status every now and then, but I don't want it's wait condition to kill another task that needs to run.

EDIT:

So I found an interesting approach that's very similar to what Hans suggested in the comments below. It comes in two pieces. One Task to happen multiple times in the middle, and one completion task to do the final clean-up. Still in testing, but it looks promising.

Here's what it looks like:

```
            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                int i = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
                {

                    foreach (var session in sessions)
                    {
                        Task work = action.Invoke(SomeParameter);
                        if (i == 50 || i == 0)
                        {
                            work.ContinueWith(task => Task.Factory.StartNew(UpdateAction));
                            i = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        ctx.ParentTask = t;

        t.ContinueWith(CompletionAction => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CompleteExecution(SomeParameter)));

        t.Start();
```

Comment: Avoid monitoring, apply the "don't call us, we'll call you" principle.  Use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext to ContinueWith() a task that runs code on the UI thread.  Same idea as BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress().

Comment: Given the need to update UI with progress, just use BackgroundWorker if you can. :)

Comment: I am not very strong in this but I would look at TPL Parallel.ForEach rather than that foreach so TPL can do what it does.

Comment: Backgroundworker will only use a single thread to process all data objects while tasks will process them in parallel. TPL makes Backgroundworker obsolete, especially in .NET 4.5 where UI updating are easily handled using the IProgress interface or async/await

Comment: Ok, the only problem with that is that my "UI" is a different process on a different machine. 3-tier architecture, and this is running in the middle tier.